# ListPlot: how to assign different markers to elements in the same list?

Tags: plotting

I'm stacked in a rather silly problem for which I can't find a solution. I have the following list that is composed of 25 elements:

```
compe = {{"COH180", "graphite", "HM", 0.331346, 0.00365217}, {"COH145","NNO", 
  "graphite", 0.459364, 0.122854}, {"COH189", "graphite", "FMQ", 0.338309, 
  0.0439558}, {"COH149", "graphite", "WM", 0.389052, 
  0.0512205}, {"COH181", "graphite", "CBN", 0.106222, 
  0.00645643}, {"COH151", "VC", "HM", 0.403467, 
  0.0430038}, {"COH152", "VC", "NNO", 0.394097, 
  0.0368108}, {"COH150", "VC", "FMQ", 0.467213, 
  0.132507}, {"COH153", "VC", "WM", 0.346076, 
  0.00775787}, {"COH174", "VC", "CBN", 0.183226, 
  0.0672226}, {"COH175", "MC", "HM", 0.365528, 
  0.0256403}, {"COH156", "MC", "NNO", 0.341335, 
  0.00557104}, {"COH154", "MC", "FMQ", 0.350248, 
  0.0164345}, {"COH157", "MC", "WM", 0.350061, 
  0.0159652}, {"COH182", "MC", "CBN", 0.315711, 
  0.00474534}, {"COH159", "GC", "HM", 0.448654, 
  0.070445}, {"COH160", "GC", "NNO", 0.378951, 
  0.0307073}, {"COH158", "GC", "FMQ", 0.408848, 
  0.0435982}, {"COH161", "GC", "WM", 0.366726, 
  0.0195669}, {"COH176", "GC", "CBN", 0.160936, 
  0.0362919}, {"COH163", "GO", "HM", 0.416089, 0.0514644}, {"COH164", 
  "GO", "NNO", 0.49324, 0.0966641}, {"COH162", "GO", "FMQ", 0.401138, 
  0.0421211}, {"COH165", "GO", "WM", 0.370123, 0.0314981}, {"COH177", 
  "GO", "CBN", 0.500647, 0.100275}}
```

This list is actually composed of 5 groups, i.e., graphite, VC, MC, GC and GO, and for each of them I could assign a color and a name in this way:

```
Grph = ListPlot[Table[compe[[l, 4 ;; 5]], {l, 1, 5, 1}], 
  PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0., 0.38, 0.58], 0.007}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Graphite"}];

VC = ListPlot[Table[compe[[l, 4 ;; 5]], {l, 6, 10, 1}], 
   PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[1., 0.51, 0.4], 0.007}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"VC"}];

MC = ListPlot[Table[compe[[l, 4 ;; 5]], {l, 11, 15, 1}], 
   PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0.5, 0.5, 0.5], 0.007}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"MC"}];

GC = ListPlot[Table[compe[[l, 4 ;; 5]], {l, 16, 20, 1}], 
   PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[1., 0.78, 0.06], 0.007}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"GC"}];

GO = ListPlot[Table[compe[[l, 4 ;; 5]], {l, 21, 25, 1}], 
   PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0.4, 0.7, 1.], 0.007}, 
   PlotLegends -> {"GO"}];
```

Now, I'm trying with no success to assign to the five elements of each group 5 different markers (possibly some shapes such as circles, triangles, etc.) that will identify in the plot the different buffers used (i.e., HM, NNO, FMQ, WM and CBN). Can someone help me?

I tried this code for the first group, but doesn't work:

```
markers = {{"\[FilledSquare]"}, {"\[FilledCircle]"}, {"\
\[FilledDiamond]"}, {"\[FilledUpTriangle]"}, \
{"\[FilledDownTriangle]"}};
Grph = ListPlot[Table[compe[[l, 4 ;; 5]], {l, 1, 5, 1}], 
  PlotStyle -> {RGBColor[0., 0.38, 0.58], 0.007}, 
  PlotLegends -> {"Graphite"}, PlotMarkers -> markers]
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Welcome to the community. Does `ListPlot[List /@ compe[[ 1 ;; 5, 4 ;; 5]], PlotLegends -> {"Graphite"}, PlotMarkers -> Flatten[markers] ]` give your desired output ?

Comment: Thank you very much Ben Izd, it works!
However, though the markers are actually as I desired, they have different colors...how can I assign the same color, say RGBColor[0., 0.38, 0.58], to all the five markers?

Comment: Use `PlotStyle -> Directive[RGBColor[0., 0.38, 0.58]]`

Comment: Super! Thank you so much!

Comment: Sorry, but I would also ask you how can I change the size of all the markers...it seems that Directive command doesn't accept the size option...

Comment: Marker size is for [`PlotMarkers`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotMarkers.html) option. Use `PlotMarkers ->Thread[{Flatten[markers], Offset[15]}]` instead.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @BenIzd Please consider turning your comments into an answer!

Answer (score 2):

Mathematica cycle through options like `PlotMarkers`. One format is `{icon1, icon2 , ... }` which is equivalent to `Flatten[markers]` on your case.

If you want to change the marker size, as [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/PlotMarkers.html) suggests, it should be passed along the marker like `{{icon1, size1}, {icon2, size2}, ...}`. Since you want all of them to be the same size, you can use `Thread`, so the `PlotMarkers` would be

```
ListPlot[ ... , PlotMarkers ->Thread[{Flatten[markers], Offset[15]}] , ... ]
```

To make all the colors the same you can use `Directive[style]` as `PlotStyle`. In your case it would be like this:

```
ListPlot[ ... , PlotStyle->Directive[RGBColor[0., 0.38, 0.58]] , ... ]
```

As a side note, instead of using `Table` to extract data, you can effectively use `Part`, like below:

```
compe[[ 1 ;; 5 , 4 ;; 5]]
```

Since you want to make each of them a separate item, map `List` so Mathematica gets your intention:

```
List /@ compe[[ 1 ;; 5 , 4 ;; 5]]
```

So the final code would look like this:

```
ListPlot[List /@ compe[[ 1 ;; 5, 4 ;; 5]], PlotLegends -> {"Graphite"}, PlotMarkers ->Thread[{Flatten[markers], Offset[15]}], PlotStyle->Directive[RGBColor[0., 0.38, 0.58]] ]
```